# When timeout and when abort occur in $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest, timeout

AngularJS 1.6.6 [has](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) support for differentiation between XHR completion, error, abort, timeout, I have this code snippet which make a request to a url like below:

```
$http.get(url, {timeout: 1000})
  .then(...)
  .catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error.xhrStatus) // could be abort, complete, error and timeout
   });
```

When requesting my api takes more than 1 second the promise is rejected with `xhrStatus` of 'abort', I was wondering in what situation I will get 'timeout' and 'error' status texts?

**Edit**: It would be awesome if the answer provide the relevant server side code in Web Api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"timeout" will never occur as far as I can tell since the xhr in the $httpBackend never has a timeout property set instead angular uses it's own mechanism for aborting the xhr request if the timeout ms expires or the promise passed in resolves.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L165

"error" will occur if a request has been dispatched and the network connection has gone down

If a 500 or 200 comes back the status will be complete but angular will fire the success or error/catch handlers on the http promise depending on the status code.

Test result model (note I disconnected the network to get the result for test3.php, the test.html page loaded, then I disconnected the network before the setTimeout fired the get hence forcing the xhr.status to error)

```
{
  "msg1": {
    "data": {
      "val": "test"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "config": {
      "method": "GET",
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
      "timeout": 1000,
      "url": "test1.php",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
    },
    "statusText": "OK",
    "xhrStatus": "complete"
  },
  "msg2": {
    "data": null,
    "status": -1,
    "config": {
      "method": "GET",
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
      "timeout": 1,
      "url": "test2.php",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
    },
    "statusText": "",
    "xhrStatus": "abort"
  },
  "msg3": {
    "data": null,
    "status": -1,
    "config": {
      "method": "GET",
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
      "url": "test3.php",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
    },
    "statusText": "",
    "xhrStatus": "error"
  },
  "msg4": {
    "data": "",
    "status": 500,
    "config": {
      "method": "GET",
      "transformRequest": [
        null
      ],
      "transformResponse": [
        null
      ],
      "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
      "url": "test4.php",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
    },
    "statusText": "Internal Server Error",
    "xhrStatus": "complete"
  }
}
```

Test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($http){
    var url1 = "test1.php";
    var url2 = "test2.php";
    var url3 = "test3.php";
    var url4 = "test4.php";

    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.model={msg1:null, msg2:null, msg3:null, msg4:null}

    $http.get(url1, {timeout: 1000})
      .then(function(resp){
        ctrl.model.msg1 = resp
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        ctrl.model.msg1 = error;
      });

    $http.get(url2, {timeout: 1})
      .then(function(resp){
        ctrl.model.msg2 = resp
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        ctrl.model.msg2 = error;
      });
    setTimeout(function(){
    $http.get(url3)
      .then(function(resp){
        ctrl.model.msg3 = resp
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        ctrl.model.msg3 = error;
      });
    }, 2000);
    $http.get(url4)
      .then(function(resp){
        ctrl.model.msg4 = resp
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        ctrl.model.msg4 = error;
      });


  });
</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
<pre>{{myCtrl.model|json}}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

test1.php

```
<?php
echo "{\"val\":\"test\"}";
```

test2.php

```
<?php
sleep(10);
```

test3.php

```
<?php
sleep(1000);
```

test4.php

```
<?php
throw new Exception("Error");
```

Comment: What is web api?

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about what server side language you prefer but honestly doesn't matter if we did the same simple spit out a response scripts in node or C# the angular side would act the same.  Please elaborate on why this isn't an acceptable answer.

Comment: you are right, I don't understand the `sleep(x)` part, is that for timeout in client side? when I will get response code of request timeout? what is its difference between client side timeout?

Comment: All the `textx.php` files are separate server side scripts used to test different response types.  The test1.php gives a valid json response (can see in the msg1 the response for test1).  test2.php just sleeps for 10 seconds which gives the 1 second client side angular timeout a chance to "abort" the request (which is what it does instead of setting xhr.timeout to the timeout time it uses it's own delay mechanism so it never actually uses "timeout" xhrStatus).

Comment: The test3.php just sleeps for 1000 seconds meant to try and test for any timeout but the msg3 shows results when I unplug network before the client sent out the request (hence the setTimeout in the client) this shows the xhr "error" status happens if the network goes down before the $http.get call happens.  The last test.php shows what happens when a server returns a 500 internal server error (xhr status "complete" but fires the "catch" or "error" promise handlers on the HttpPromise)